# How to create efficient index for mongoDB with equals and sorting by date ASC and DESC

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

In my database I want to create some index which helps me search faster things like this:

```
db.getCollection('mycoll').find( {product: {$eq: "bread"}}).sort({date: 1})
db.getCollection('mycoll').find( {product: {$eq: "bread"}}).sort({date: -1})
```

In documentation I readed:

> For example, an index key pattern { a: 1, b: -1 } can support a sort
>   on { a: 1, b: -1 } and { a: -1, b: 1 } but not on { a: -1, b: -1 } or
>   {a: 1, b: 1}.

But I want to sort only for one field -date. 
How to create the best index for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-index-prefix reads:

> If the sort keys correspond to the index keys or an index prefix, MongoDB can use the index to sort the query results. A prefix of a compound index is a subset that consists of one or more keys at the start of the index key pattern.

An index `{date:1, product:1}` will support both queries.

Comment: thanks, you have right :) A second ago I checked it in explain("executionStats") both queries using index, but when I created index pattern like this:  `{date:1, product:1}`  sorting by `date: -1` takes twice more time than `date: 1`

Comment: It shouldn't. Try few more times. If the results are consistent ask a new question providing details about the collection, db version, and results of explain.

Comment: Ok, I checked and next time it took similar time :) Thanks ! :)